# rails 3 nested resource `new` path being switched

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, spree, nested-resources

I don't quite get why this is happening, maybe someone of you does... here it goes.

I've created a nested resource:

```
resources :order do
  resources :ordered_vehicles
end
```

I've added a `link_to` the `new` action and passed the `order.id` like so `new_order_ordered_vehicle_path(order.id)` the page is loaded nicely. The problem is after I press the button to submit the choice. He switches the path from `http://localhost:3000/order/3/ordered_vehicles/new` to `http://localhost:3000/order/R076027535/ordered_vehicles` and displays error `Couldn't find Order with id=R076027535`... go figure.

The error is being raised in the controller in this method

```
private
  def find_order
    @order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
  end
```

Which is a `before_filter`.

the `new.html.haml` file looks like this

```
= form_for [@order, @ordered_vehicle], html: { multipart: true } do |f|
  = @order.number
  %br= @order.id
    = f.fields_for :vehicles do |car|
      .... #some fields here
      = car.submit "Save your choice"
```

That `id` he can't find is the `@order.number` but I don't get why the switch.

EDIT:
Just to be thorough, I'll add the controller methods:

```
def new
  @ordered_vehicle = @order.ordered_vehicles.build(params.slice(:order_id, :vehicle_id))
end

def create
  binding.pry
  @ordered_vehicle = @order.ordered_vehicles.build(params.slice(:order_id, :vehicle_id))
  if @ordered_vehicle.save
    flash[:notice] = "Save successful."
    redirect_to account_path
  end
end
```

POST request (I hope that's the one, still new to all this stuff):

```
"action_dispatch.request.formats"=>[text/html]},
 @request_method="POST", @filtered_parameters={"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>
 "Ar4vy8pqCSpA2ch0qG0qiJXAJUbNALYxm/FbuKbdzCc=", "ordered_vehicle"=>
 {"vehicles"=>   {"maker_id"=>"", "model_id"=>"", "year"=>"", "body"=>"", "capacity"=>"", "id"=>"1"}},
 "commit"=>"Save your choice", "action"=>"create",
 "controller"=>"spree/ordered_vehicles", "order_id"=>"R076027535"}, @method="POST",
 @fullpath="/order/R076027535/ordered_vehicles">
```

Comment: Can you show me your routes? And can you show me the url that is actually rendered from `form_for [@order, @ordered_vehicle]`. Also, what is "R076027535" Is that the ID of the ordered_vehicle?

Comment: I've posted the routes (first code). The "R07..." is the `@order.number` just another column in the `Orders` table, don't know why he switches. The url? The only one I get is `http://localhost:3000/order/R076027535/ordered_vehicles` after the submit button is pressed.

Comment: So it's POSTing to `http://localhost:3000/order/R076027535/ordered_vehicles`. That's strange. Try switching your form_for to `form_for [@order.id, @ordered_vehicle]`

Comment: `undefined method ``model_name' for Fixnum:Class` his response. what's even more strange is that this `before_filter` is called before `new` and no problems. But, when it comes to `create` all hell brakes loose...

Comment: Can you show me the output of your POST request?

Comment: On that `[@order.id, @ordered_vehicle]` he won't even let me go to POST. As soon as he tries to render the `new.html.haml` page, the error `undefined method` goes of.

Comment: Yeah remove that, that's was a bad recommendation on my part. Try what you had and then past the output.

Comment: Yea, I did. Updated my original post with the answer.

Comment: You should add this as an answer and accept it instead of editing your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per request ;)

Well, it turned out to be a problem with `Spree` which I'm currently tweaking (I know I didn't mention it explicitly, but didn't want to just post too much information).

Bottom line:

In the `Order` model the method `to_param` was overwritten to pass the `number` column in to the `params`. Didn't overwrote it again, just left it there and adapted. In my `find_order` method I wrote:

```
  def find_order
    @order = Order.find_by_number(params[:order_id])
  end
```

Also I've stored the order number in the table, there was a problem I believe with out that, but can't remember explicitly. Anyways, thanks for the help.

P.S. Sorry for the mess